# Send email only if the job fails

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, lsf

I have the following array job setup:

```
#BSUB -J "myArray[1-50]"
#BSUB -o o.%J.%I
#BSUB -e e.%J.%I
#BSUB -W 10:00
#BSUB -N
#BSUB -u myEmail@somewhere.com
```

This will send me 50 emails once the jobs are complete, something like this in the title:

```
Email1: Job 123456[1]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Done
Email2: Job 123456[2]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Done
...
Email50: Job 123456[50]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Done
```

Is it possible to send email **only** if the job has failed. For example if 11th, 12th, and 25th jobs have failed out of 50 jobs, I will only get 3 emails?

```
Email1: Job 123456[11]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Exited
Email2: Job 123456[12]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Exited
Email3: Job 123456[25]: <myArray[1-50]> in cluster <xyz-cluster> Exited
```

Let me know if anything unclear.

Answer (score 0):

LSF App Center has a notification feature that can send emails when a job ends or starts, please check this out for configuration: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZRJV_10.2.0/manage_jobs/submit_jobs_help.html